# Enabling Onclick method for Fb-button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false" onclick="alert('1')">
</div>
```

I had render JS-SDK from fb-developers,

```
 (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I need to take another action after login in FB, is there any method which I missed to achieve what I need?

As a sample, I added code snippet in above example `onclick="alert('1')"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

You have to use `onlogin`, not `onclick`.